# Enforce field initialization order in TypeScript class constructor

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to let the TypeScript (4.0) compiler enforce the correct initialization order of class fields in the constructor?

In the following example ([run](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC3QN4CgECcCmYAmB7AdiAJ7QAeAXNPgK4C2ARhmqtJjgcdEZTQ08i2AEIAFzTVgI3GgAUFKnUZoAlCgQIRACwCWEAHQkAvNC2692-NpEBNGcpYad+0tGOkWAXwEIADmm0AbmAiGNAWVrbKPIpMSA6sGCLUaPgmTnouANTQAIyeyF7IQvgQuCAYeiC4AOYy+BgA7nAyOcoGykA)) `this.x` is accessed in the method `initY` before `this.x` is initialized in the constructor:

```
class A  {
  readonly x: number
  readonly y: number

  constructor(x: number){
    this.y = this.initY() // this.x not initialized yet
    this.x = x
  }

  private initY(): number {
    return this.x + 1
  }
}

console.log(new A(1).y) // prints: NaN
```

The best I came up with is using a static method or top-level function to perform the initialization.

Any better (more concise) ideas? Is it possible to let the compiler (already in strict mode) or linter find this kind of issue?

Comment: Why not simply move the this.x above this.y? Sounds more like a logical error in code not like a compile time error

Comment: @MartinGodzina Because this is the sort of mistake one could make in *any* application, and determining the logic failure currently has to be done individually (if detected at all). Having TS (or some other structure) warn a code-writer *at compile time* instead of at runtime (if such a mistake is detected at all, which it might not be!) of such an issue would be better.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I don't think it's possible. If I were you, I'd avoid it by writing in a more functional style.

Comment: You could also use static code analysis tools as a quality gate in your CI/CD pipelines. Sonarcloaud for example will notify these lines of code a 'bug'.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to set the member as nullable types, to enforce typeguards check before using a nullable variables.

This behavior can be achieved by declaring the member x and y as a union of `number | null`

```
class A  {
  readonly x: number | null
  readonly y: number | null

  constructor(x: number){
    this.y = this.initY() // this.x not initialized yet
    this.x = x
  }

  private initY(): number {
    // wont compile you need to check for null first
    return this.x + 1
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a workaround, but it'll require you to type check *everywhere*, which will lead to a huge amount of boilerplate.

Comment: The idea is not bad in principle, but wouldn't really solve the issue. Maybe null checks would avoid hard runtime errors, but what should happen instead? If there is a hard dependency between two fields that cannot be handled properly. It must be handled by the compiler or another tool that performs static code analysis. However, nullable types could be used for explicit checks that would throw errors instead of hiding this error and returning erroneous results.